# ¿Cómo conservar permisos al subir archivos nuevos?

Tags: linux

Tengo unos dominios en un servidor con Apache a los cuales les asigné un usuario y grupo:

```
sudo chown -R usuario:apache /var/www/dominio.com
```

Y funciona para poder editar y subir archivos con ese usuario. El problema está en que los archivos nuevos no parecen tener los permisos que tienen los archivos que ya estaban en el directorio al ejecutar el comando chown

Comment: Te refieres a que no quedan con el mismo owner? Porque con el `chown` no estás cambiando los permisos. Muéstranos un ejemplo de los archivos que existen vs los que se suben

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente sea debido a que Apache tiene su propia mascara, deberías poder encontrarla aqui: /usr/local/apache/bin/envvars

Comment: Por lo general Apache no crea archivos, salvo que se haga una solicitud dle tipo `PUT` la cuál es extraña que la hagan los navegadores web. Si utilizas Apache junto con `mod_cgi`, deberás cambiar la máscara por defecto. Si utilizas Php basta que hagas `umask(0)` antes de crear un archivo